# Не соединяется приложение as3 и сервер через сокет после переноса в контакт

Tags: actionscript-3, сокеты, вконтакте

Здравствуйте!
Пишу приложение для вконтакта. В нем используется взаимодействие с сервером через Socket. Сервер находится в интернете (не на локальном компе). Когда запускаю клиента с локального компа, то все работает. А когда загружаю вконтакт, то клиент не соединяется с сервером. Иногда выдается ошибка 2048. Файл crossdomain.xml есть, с ним как уже только не экспериментировал. Вот его содержимое :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Причем запросы к скриптам работают нормально, а вот именно сокеты - нет.
Подскажите, что может быть не так?

Answer (score 1):

когда подключение из AS идет *через сокет*, то crossdomain.xml не достаточно, надо с сервера отправлять сокетную политику безопасности. 
По умолчанию - **через порт 843**.
Вот, кажется [здесь](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=193211) есть обсуждение по теме.

Для вконтакта обычно эта стратегия выглядит как-то так:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*.vkontakte.ru" to-ports="11111"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*.vk.com" to-ports="11111"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Возможно, что еще следует разрешить доступ к папке клиентского приложения (если тестируете swf локально) в [настройках безопасности](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html)

Comment: Локально все работает. Сейчас все перепроверил через Putty. Сервер по 843 порту на запрос <policy-file-request/> возвращает такой ответ:
<cross-domain-policy> <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/> </cross-domain-policy>
То есть сервер работает правильно. Через инструменты для разработчика в Google Chrome отслеживаю входящую информацию при загрузке флешки из вконтакта. Файлы crossdomain от самого вконтакта и от второго сервера (на котором скрипты) скачиваются, а с сокетного сервера нет ничего. Попробовал не вконтакте разместить, а на другом сервере, тоже самое.